# SKCameraNode’s physicsBody does not react to forces

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I want to apply an impulse to the physicsbody of my camera. It is properly initialized and has `isDynamic` set to `true`. However, it does not respond to forces at all. Setting the velocity also does nothing.

I couldn’t find anything related to this when researching. I’ve tried to applying impulses to a plain SKNode, which works just fine.

Setting the physicsbody:

```swift
    myCamera.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
    myCamera.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
```

Trying to apply the impulse:

```swift
    myCamera.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 5, dy: 0))
```

The camera should move in response to the impulse, but instead does nothing.

Comment: did you add the camera to the scene?

Comment: Yes I did @Knight0fDragon. I can manipulate its position manually.

Comment: That doesnt mean you added it to the scene, you have to do `addChild(camera)` as well as `scene.camera = camera`